# Programmatically change NIB checkboxes

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to set my nib properties programmatically. Specifically, I have a view controller which I initialized with a nib, and now I'm trying to programmatically [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid] but it never sets it.

My mapView is an IBOutlet MKMapView, and I dragged a Map View into my nib and conected mapView to Map View.

If I set the Type in the Attributes Inspector of the Map View, it works fine. Is there a way to do this programmatically?

I gave up trying to use nibs months ago (shortly after I started with XCode), but it would be really nice to figure this out.
Thanks

**MapTabViewController.h**

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapTabViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
```

**MapTabViewController.m**

```
-(id) initWithTabBarAndNibName: (NSString *) nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

if (self) {
    self.title = MAPTAB_TITLE;
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:MAPTAB_ICON];

    self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    [self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];

}
return self;
```

}

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.dataModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

vc_tacTab = [[TacTabViewController alloc] initWithTabBarAndNibName:@"TacTabViewController" bundle: nil];
vc_tacTab.dataModel = self.dataModel;

vc_mapTab = [[MapTabViewController alloc] initWithTabBarAndNibName:@"MapTabViewController" bundle:nil];
vc_mapTab.dataModel = self.dataModel;

NSArray *localControllersArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:vc_tacTab, vc_mapTab, nil];

tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;

[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];


self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
```

Here you are destroying the value in your outlet, and replacing it with a new mapview, which will never be displayed.

When loading from the nib, the outlets will be populated with the objects you have linked them to in the nib. Remove this line and you should be fine.

**EDIT** - Just realised where this code is being executed. The outlet won't be populated yet - you need to set the property in viewDidLoad, not in the overridden initializer - in fact, all of that code would be better placed in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thank you jrturton. That's something I didn't know and gives me a good starting point to research. Removing that line didn't make my map show up in hybrid mode but it's a key piece of information I was missing.

Comment: I've amended my answer, it won't work where you are trying it.